# Creating a JSON-LD Context: Properties missing

Tags: jsonschema, json-ld

I try to create my own Context for a project. However, after using Compact some Properties will be missing. Please see this example:

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "myvocab": "http://localhost:8080/schema.json#",
    "Information":
    {
      "@id": "myvocab:Information",
      "@type": "@id",
      "name": "http://schema.org/name",
      "active": "http://schema.org/Boolean"
    }
  },

  "Information": [
   {
     "@type": "myvocab:Information",
     "name": "myCustomName",
     "active": "true"    
   }
  ]
}
```

This example can also be found on the [JSON-LD Playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/index.html#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22myvocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fschema.json%23%22%2C%22Information%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22myvocab%3AInformation%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22active%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FBoolean%22%7D%7D%2C%22Information%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22myvocab%3AInformation%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22myCustomName%22%2C%22active%22%3A%22true%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22myvocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fschema.json%23%22%2C%22Information%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22myvocab%3AInformation%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22active%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FBoolean%22%7D%7D%7D).
After Compacting, I cannot see the properties "name" and "active" anymore as they will be removed. This is also the case in the playground. However, I do not get an error in the @context part, so I assume it is correct.

Please help me to understand why that properies go missing and what I could do to see them correctly after parsing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting of your context is wrong. You mistakenly made `name` and `active` attributes of the `Information` mapping instead of making them term mappings on their own. Here's the fixed example:

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "myvocab": "http://localhost:8080/schema.json#",
    "Information":
    {
      "@id": "myvocab:Information",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "active": "http://schema.org/Boolean"
  },
  "Information": [
   {
     "@type": "myvocab:Information",
     "name": "myCustomName",
     "active": "true"    
   }
  ]
}
```

You might also want to check the mapping of `active`. You map it to a type instead of mapping it to a property (properties are lowercased in Schema.org, classes/types capitalized).

Comment: Hello Markus, thank you very much for your reply and this works. However, I wonder what I can do if I want to have more than one type. Would that look like this? `{
  "@context":
  {
    "myvocab": "http://localhost:8080/schema.json#",
    "Information":
    {
      "@id": "myvocab:Information",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "active": "http://schema.org/Boolean",
    
    "OtherInformation":
    {
      "@id": "myvocab:Information",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "otherName": "http://schema.org/name",
    "otherActive": "http://schema.org/Boolean"
  }`

Comment: Especially, I wonder how the paramters "name" and "active" are considered part of "Information" and not, for example. "OtherInformation".